# Estimation of standard error in observables generated from time series data

Tags: time-series, standard-error, error, independence

Imagine that I have time series data which are time-correlated, non-scalar, and of unknown, but identical distribution

[image: Text]

From this time series I have a function that takes an subset of X as input to calculate a scalar quantity Q

[image: Text]

What I would like to know is how do you estimate the standard deviation of [image: Text] ? That is to say the standard deviation of the quantity calculated by passing the full dataset to function F. I have seen methods of dealing with time-correlated data before. For example if each random variable [image: text] were a scalar and we wanted to calculate the standard error of the mean of the underlying distribution, we could use the [Block Averaging](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.457480) method. Does an analogous technique exist for this case where I am trying to estimate the standard deviation of [image: Text] ?

I should further note that for my case [image: Text] converges for large sample sizes (i.e. when N is large) and because of this I am using [image: Text] as an estimator for the quantity calculated if the entire population were passed to function F. Also, the range of the function is [image: Text] and has the property [image: Text] (the function applied to any single data point always gives a value equal to 1)